# jquery mobile listview right to left?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, right-to-left, hebrew

i am trying to change the code from jquerymobile samples to right to left i tryed few css but non workt

http://jsfiddle.net/erone/c3mhm677/1/

```
                <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Friday, October 8, 2010 <span class="ui-li-count">2</span></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">

                <h3>סתם לבדיקה</h3>
                <p><strong>יום טוב </strong></p>
                <p>תודה על הכל :)</p>
                <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>6:24</strong>PM</p>

        </a></li>
```

Comment: Have you tried this one ? http://www.intlaqa.com/jquery-mobile-rtl/

Comment: did not ,thx il try it right now

Answer (score 1):

In CssFile : Use bellow code to change text align of List View items to right to left :

```
.ui-listview > .ui-li-static, .ui-listview > .ui-li-divider, .ui-listview > li > a.ui-btn {
        text-align: right;
    }
```

In HTML : And bellow code for change icon position of List View items to left :

```
<li>
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-carat-l">
</a>
</li>
```